# How can I make the contents of a table cell overflow vertically without also expanding the table cells height?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table cell with a `div` inside. I want the `div` to overflow outside of the table cell. How can I make this happen? To be clear, I don't want the table cell to expand its height with the `div`. The code below is what I have tried, but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell">
            <div class="overflow">Overlow outside of this cell</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    height:24px;
    overflow:visible;
}
.cell {
    overflow:visible;
    max-height:24px !important;
}
.overflow {
    height:24px;
    font-size:12px;
    clear:both;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height:16px;
    zoom:1;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I get you right, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7zps4/) might help:

```css
.row {
  height: 24px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.cell {
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 24px !important;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 10px;
}

.overflow {
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell">
      <div class="overflow">Overlow outside of this cell</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.overflow {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: I doubt that this solves the problem or even works at all. To convince me otherwise, please explain how this works and why it answers the question.

Comment: You can do very well here, grow your reputation, get and give answers to questions but please answer properly. Thousands or millions of people are skimming answers and should not have to reverse engineer code and guess about what answers are trying to accomplish to see if it solves their problem. It wastes everyone's time. Please edit your answer and post a brief description.