# Is it possible to expand a nested div to the exact position of some outer element?

Tags: html, css, extjs

On my page I have a grid (mostly ExtJs), created out of a bunch of nested tables and divs.
In particular the inner-most div (representing an element inside the grid cell) is nested in two other tables (and their corresponding trs and tds of course).

I want this inner-most div to expand across table boundaries to the bottom of the corresponding div in a cell below (as shown on the attached diagram).
Effectively using up two grid cells (or even more - 3, 4 etc. vertically).

Is this even possible? I know of no such way (other than explicitly specifying the height, which might be pretty difficult, since it varies between cells), but my HTML/CSS skills are quite limited.
If it's possible, could you point me in some direction?

Some other details:

- rows in the grid can be of variable height, dependent on the size of elements in their cells
- the black line on the diagram represents the grid[image]

Comment: post your html and css and if possible provide a demo.

Comment: You are going to need to play with the position attribute. here is a cool site explaining positioning http://learnlayout.com/position.html its helped me before.

Comment: Thanks for that link... I always have trouble with CSS layouts so this site might prove pretty useful :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the contents of a table exceeds its boundaries if you play a little with

```
{position: relative;  
top: -40px}
```

for the div in the table. Though i'd think of a more elegant solution.

check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SkX7T/

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I know it IS possible for the contents to exceed the boundaries (i.e. as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621712/how-can-i-make-the-contents-of-a-table-cell-overflow-vertically-without-also-exp). What I don't know is how to align the contents with something else.